# Previously followed links don't change on hover

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

When I have followed a link (the top one) it doesn't change when I hover. However, the non followed one does:

[image: second link changing colour on hover animation]

Could the followed link change to another colour on hover please? For example, on English Language & Usage, both types of link change to be underlined. I'm not suggesting we use underlining here but something would be nice.