# Inverted color of visited links in some tabs of user profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, hyperlinks

I am puzzled by the color of links in the [votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes):

- non-visited links are  grey `#555555`
- visited links are  blue `#36649d`

Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Same thing in [all actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) and [responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses). Besides Meta, I saw this on Stack Overflow and Mathematics... my opinion is that the colors make LESS sense after the redesign.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251847/previously-followed-links-dont-change-on-hover